# What is the version of my debian system?

Tags: linux

Maybe this is a stupid question.

I would like to know how do I know what is the version of my debian system.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply run "lsb_release -a" from the command line or "cat /etc/lsb-release"

Comment: Although `lsb_release -a` is much more informative, `cat /etc/debian_version` is another alternative.

Comment: The lsb_release command is actually optional. See distribution specific files otherwise (/etc/debian_version, /etc/redhat-release ...)

Answer (score 6):

If you know that you are on a Debian or derivative, check the file `/etc/debian_version`. This will have the version number of the currently installed system.

If you want something more generic, look at (particularly) the `PRETTY_NAME`, `NAME`, `VERSION` and `VERSION_ID` values in `/etc/os-release`. This file is actually a shell script that you can source into your own scripts, to do things differently on different distributions.

On "true" Debian, both of the above are provided by the `base-files` package. Derivatives may be different.

Again if you know you are on a Debian system, you can also check the output of `apt-cache show base-files` to see which version of the `base-files` package is installed. This also might not work on Debian derivatives.

If you want to know the version of the kernel that is currently running, you can use `uname` for that. For example, `uname -a` to print all information, or `uname -rv` to print the specific kernel version with little extra information. In many cases, you should not need to do this, as what you do should not depend on the specific kernel version installed.

Comment: Note that this answer was originally posted to http://superuser.com/q/950410/53590, which was significantly edited after I posted the above answer.