# How to find out what Debian version I am using?

Tags: debian

I have access to a Debian machine via SSH. 
How do I find out what version of Debian is installed?

This is possibly a duplicate of [What is the version of my debian system?](https://superuser.com/questions/627716/what-is-the-version-of-my-debian-system).

That question is answered by:

- lsb_release -a
- cat /etc/lsb-release

There is another answer in one of the comments:

- cat /etc/debian_version

lsb_release -a does not work:

```
-bash: lsb_release: command not found
```

Nor does cat /etc/lsb-release:

```
cat: /etc/lsb-release: No such file or directory
```

I suppose that

```
cat /etc/debian_version
```

is the way to go as it gives me "8.1".

```
apt-cache show base-files
```

returns a bunch of properties including "Version: 8+deb8u1". How is the version of the base-files package related to the Debian version? I assume that the "deb8u1" part translates into "8.1". What does the first "8+" part mean then?

```
uname -a
```

returns

```
Linux deb2 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u2 (2015-07-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and

```
uname -rv
```

returns

```
3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u2 (2015-07-17)
```

How is the kernel version related to the Debian version? Does a specific Debian version always include the same kernel?

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

returns amongst other properties:

```
VERSION_ID="8"
```

So, for me "8" and "8.1" seem to be different. Is "8" the "generic Debian version"? How do you call "8.1" then ("full version"?) ?

Comment: How do you mean "version"? Distro? Linux kernel version? `uname` can help with this...

Comment: This could be part of the answer. If I say "I have a Debian machine." the next question would probably be "which Debian?". That's what I would call "version". If it's more complicated, please explain.

Comment: Please don't change your question after people answered it.

Comment: @Arjan: Concerning the possible duplicate I was explicitely asked to edit the question.

Comment: My answer is now at http://superuser.com/a/950436/53590 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Kjörling gave you a great answer. His way should be preferred. But here's another way to get the generic Debian version.

Just check /etc/apt/sources.list 
It states which version it is to find the right updates.

Cheers

Comment: Now I know, I am on stable! :)